# List all the revisions in a mixed revision SVN working copy

Tags: linux, bash, svn

SVN working copy has [mixed revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs) in the general case. Is there a way to list all its revision numbers?

For example, for the following working copy:

```
file01   (revision 1)
file02   (revision 2)
file02.2 (revision 2)
file03   (revision 3)
```

The list of the revisions would be `1, 2, 3`.

`svnversion` comes close, but not close enough:

```
$ svnversion
1:3
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443647/how-can-i-see-the-revision-number-of-each-file-in-a-svn-working-copy.

Comment: I don't get why `svn status` or `svn status -v` does not work for you. Or does it?

Comment: @bahrep `svn status` simply gives empty output, no revision numbers at all. `svn status -v` is way too... verbose. I don't see any additional flags to make it output just a list of unique revision numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `svn info`, `awk` and `sed`, this

```
svn info -R | awk '/Revision/ {print $2;}' | sort -u
```

produces the following if invoked in the working directory root:

```
1
2
3
```

Such multi-line output can further be transformed into single-line form using techniques from [Bash turning multi-line string into single comma-separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714355/bash-turning-multi-line-string-into-single-comma-separated) question. E.g.

```
svn info -R | awk '/Revision/ {print $2;}' | sort -u | paste -s -d,
```

produces `1,2,3`.